# Equivalent of a "require" statement in ES6: *.plugin(require('*'))

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, pouchdb

I have the following two statements in ES5:

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
```

I want to implement two statements in ES6 like below:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
???
```

I don't know how to implement the second statement in ES6

Comment: Won't these two statements work as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this first:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBAuth from 'pouchdb-authentication';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBAuth);
```

Since `import` is static in ES6, you may need to give it its own line.

Comment: @brk what is the question?  It is just a name for the `default` export of `pouchdb-authentication` used in this module.

Comment: It's not clear, but it's just as likely that `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';` is what you want.